# How to decrypt TLS traffic of a test device port forwarded to a device with Wireshark?

Tags: ssl, encryption, wireshark, traffic

I am decrypting network encrypted packets of a test device. I am following the youtube video below, and have included the content of my key file. I am unable to decrypt.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQtur8fqErI

Keyfile content: https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#SSL_with_decryption_keys

### My set up is like this;

I have apple tv connected to a Cisco switch with port mirroring capability. I have my test laptop connected to the same switch with Wireshark installed. I have set up port mirroring in the switch to send network packets of Apple TV to my laptop's port. I start Wireshark to watch all calls. I can see all network calls, but the ones are encrypted not decrypting. I have added the key file as per the video but still not working.

I would really appreciate anyone's help. Thanks all.

Comment: And where the Apple TV connects to? (what is the target service?)  To decrypt SSL traffic you need the private key of the target endpoint. Are you connecting to a custom streaming service of your own? Or you are connecting to an external  streaming service?

Comment: the apple tv connected to same network as my laptop with wireshark. I am testing our own app. is that waht you mean by custom streaming service? cheers;